Break from scheduleAtFixedRate when condition met
I have few functions with @Schedule annotation e.g
@Autowired
private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;


@Scheduled(cron = "0 45 07 ? * MON,WED,SUN")
public void sendDailyQuestionFatherDrop() {
   wrapMessageWithRetires(...)
}


@Scheduled(cron = "0 45 07 ? * TUE,THU")
public void sendDailyQuestionFatherDrop() {
   wrapMessageWithRetires(...)
}

My scheduler config:
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class TaskSchedulerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
        taskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("TaskScheduler-");
        taskScheduler.initialize();
        return taskScheduler;
    }
}

and my wrapMessageWithRetries:
 private void wrapMessageWithRetires(SendMessage message, String toCall, String name, String phoneInTextSpeech, String escalationNumber) {
        AtomicInteger retries = new AtomicInteger(0);
        taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            if (answerReceived) {
                answerReceived = false;
                log.info("Answer received, stopping retries.");
                return;
            }

            log.info("Retrying sending message attempts number {}", retries.get());

            if (retries.incrementAndGet() > 3) {
                taskScheduler.stop();
                SendMessage callToPhoneNumber = SendMessage.builder()
                        .chatId(fatherMomGroupChatId)
                        .text(String.format(MessageTemplates.NO_RESPONSE_AFTER_RETRIES_MSG, name, name))
                        .build();

                sendQuestion(callToPhoneNumber);

                log.info("After {} attempts no one answered. Going to call to phone number: {}", retries.get(), toCall);
                twilioService.initialCall(toCall, phoneInTextSpeech, escalationNumber);
            } else {
                sendQuestion(message);
            }
        }, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    }

The issue that I am facing now is that when my retries reach 3, I don't want to continue running this schedule and I want to break from that specific one. I initially tried using taskScheduler.shutdown() inside my if statement, but that also shut down my next @Schedule.
My goal is to just shut down the first schedule if I find that answerReceived, and not interrupt the flow to ensure that my next schedule will run.
I haven't found a satisfactory solution yet.
